# How to change the default spring framework version in STS?

Tags: spring, frameworks

Is there any possible option to change the default version of spring framework in spring tool suit 3.9.1. Currently i am having default spring framework version of 3.1.1 being used in sts-3.9.1-RELEASE.

And i want to set the default version value to be latest version of spring framework 5.0.2.

How to?

Comment: The version of STS has nothing to do with the spring version (that is the version internally used) you can use whatever you like. Just use something like maven or gradle to manage those dependencies.

Comment: I know this method but what i want is to set the framework version to 5.0.2 when creating the project as a default framework version instead of 3.1.1 in pom.xml